# Addition Problem with Missing Digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

In the addition problem shown each $\ast$ denotes a missing digit and the $\ast$'s are not necessarily identical. What final four digit sum will result from the proper restoration of the missing digits?

```
   82*
   1*9
+ 1*64
------
  1**9
```

Comment: To clarify the question was what final four digit sum will result from the proper restoration of the missing digits 82* + 1*9 + 1*64 equals 1**9

Comment: I edited your post. Please make sure my edits are correct.

Comment: Yes they are correct

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your post to include anything you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I plugged in numbers but haven't found any answer. I don't have any strategy unfortunately other then just guessing

Comment: **Hint:** $d=9+c; e=9+b; 3+a=9$. Try to see why and reply back if you're stuck after a while.

Comment: I don't understand the variables and what I have to do with them

Comment: @JeremiahBradley They denote, respectively, the missing numbers from top left to bottom right.

Comment: Start with the top-right asterisk. What do you think that one should be?

Comment: That's obviously a 6 sir

Comment: Good, now what about the one in the third row? The 1*64?

Comment: is it zero? As the value of *

Comment: It is zero. How do you know it's zero? And what does this mean about the $\ast$ just below it?

Comment: So is the final four digit sum 1999?

Comment: That's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a sum of the form
$$
S = [8(100)+2(10)+a]+[1(100)+b(10)+9] + [1(1000)+c(100)+6(10)+4],
$$
where all of this equals
$$
1(1000)+d(100)+e(10)+9.
$$
Now consider that
\begin{align}
S &= (800+20+100+9+1000+60+4)+(100c+10b+a)\\[0.5em]
  &= 1993 + (100c+10b+a).
\end{align}
Thus, we have that
$$
1993 + (100c+10b+a) = 1(1000)+d(100)+e(10)+9.
$$
We can represent this more sensibly as
$$
1(1000)+(9+c)(100)+(9+b)(10)+(3+a)=1(1000)+d(100)+e(10)+9.
$$
Look at how the parts of the equation relate. You can see that we must have the following:

- $9+c = d$
- $9+b = e$
- $3+a = 9$

Comment: You just hit a nail with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @mapierce271 I don't know what the purpose of that comment is, but the kind of thinking I outlined is what the OP *should* be thinking in the future to solve generalized problems of this sort (such as the famous $1089$ magic trick).

Comment: So is the final four digit sum 1999?

Comment: @JeremiahBradley The three equations I outlined at the end are all you need. Since you are working in base $10$, no number $a,\ldots,e$ can be $10$ or more (that is, the numbers $a,\ldots,e$ must *all* be less than $10$). Thus, $9+c=d$ implies that $c=0$ and $d=9$. Also, $9+b=e$ implies that $b=0$ and $e=9$. We clearly have that $a=6$ since $3+a=9$. Thus, now all you have to do is plug in the numbers: $$82a+1b9+1c64=1de9 \Longleftrightarrow 826+109+1064=1999.$$