# Smallest rectangle satisfying certain conditions

Tags: geometry, area

What is the least possible area of a rectangle whose sides and diagonals all have positive integral lengths? I tried picking random numbers but don't have any strategy for this

Comment: First find a single example of a rectangle with integer side-lengths and diagonals. We can work from there. (**Hint**: think of right triangles and the Pythagorean theorem)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Two sides of a rectangle, and its diagonal, form the three sides of a right triangle.  Do you know any right triangles whose three sides are all integers?  If not, do you know any theorem relating the sides of a right triangle?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem ?

Comment: And what does the Pythagorean theorem say?

Comment: A squared plus b squared equals the length of the hypotenusec squared

Comment: So you need to find three positive integers, $a,b,$ and $h$, with $a^2 + b^2 = h^2$.  Can you do that?

Comment: 3,4,5 but it says i

Comment: 3,4,5 5,12,13 but it says positive integral lengths and whose sides are diagonals

Comment: @JeremiahBradley It doesn't say "whose sides *are* diagonals", it says "whose sides **and** diagonals are of positive integer length."

Comment: I think you need to stop typing comments and start thinking more about the hints you already have. Maybe draw some diagrams.

Comment: Okay I give up I'm just dumb

Comment: You can't control how dumb you are, but you *can* control whether you give up. Why are you choosing to be dumber than you have to be?

Comment: @Jeremiah: *Too impatient* seems more likely. Stop and draw a right triangle. Can you find a way to combine it with a congruent right triangle so as to make a rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

One, two, that won’t do.
Three, four, five,
Sakes alive!

Comment: So the least possible area you're telling me Mr Scott is there's is no value ?

Comment: @Jeremiah: No, I’m not saying that at all. Keep pursuing **MJD**’s hint; my hint is almost certainly too obscure.

Comment: Can you just make life easier please and tell me the answer

Comment: @JeremiahBradley That's not how this site works. Just like in your other [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149993/addition-problem-with-missing-digits), it's like you didn't even bother to read my answer. All you wanted to know was what the correct answer is.

Comment: @JeremiahBradley, that is the ABSOLUTE WORST possible attitude to have when asking for help on this site, and when learning mathematics in general.

Comment: (+1) I thought this was a really cute answer. Must have been fun having you in the classroom!